# Lucene Index - single term and phrase querying

Tags: java, lucene

I've read some documents and build a lucene index which looks like

Documents:

```
id        1
keyword   foo bar
keyword   john

id        2
keyword   foo

id        3
keyword   john doe
keyword   bar foo
keyword   what the hell
```

I want to query lucene in a way, where I can combine single term and phrases.

Let's say my query is

```
foo bar
```

should give back the doc ids 1, 2 and 3

The query

```
"foo bar"
```

should give back the doc ids 1

The query

```
john
```

should give back the doc ids 1 and 3

The query

```
john "foo bar"
```

should give back the doc ids 1

My implementation in java is not working. Also reading tons of documents didn't help.

When I query my index with

```
"foo bar"
```

I get 0 hits

When I query my index with

```
foo "john doe"
```

I get back the doc ids 1, 2 and 3 (i would expect only doc id 3 since the query is meant as foo AND "john doe") The problem is, that "john doe" gives back 0 hits but foo gives back 3 hits.

My goal is to combine single term and phrase terms. What am I doing wrong? I've also played around with the analyzers with no luck.

My implementation looks like this:

## Indexer

```
  import ...

  public class Indexer
  {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Indexer.class);

    private final File indexDir;

    private IndexWriter writer;

    public Indexer(File indexDir)
    {
    this.indexDir = indexDir;
    this.writer = null;
  }

  private IndexWriter createIndexWriter()
  {
    try
    {
      Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(indexDir);
      Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_34);
      IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_34, analyzer);
      iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
      iwc.setRAMBufferSizeMB(256.0);
      IndexWriter idx = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
      idx.deleteAll();
      return idx;
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Could create indexer on directory [%s]", indexDir.getAbsolutePath()), e);
    }
  }

  public void index(TestCaseDescription desc)
  {
    if (writer == null)
      writer = createIndexWriter();

    Document doc = new Document();
    addPathToDoc(desc, doc);
    addLastModifiedToDoc(desc, doc);
    addIdToDoc(desc, doc);
    for (String keyword : desc.getKeywords())
      addKeywordToDoc(doc, keyword);

    updateIndex(doc, desc);
  }

  private void addIdToDoc(TestCaseDescription desc, Document doc)
  {
    Field idField = new Field(LuceneConstants.FIELD_ID, desc.getId(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
    idField.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_ONLY);
    doc.add(idField);
  }

  private void addKeywordToDoc(Document doc, String keyword)
  {
    Field keywordField = new Field(LuceneConstants.FIELD_KEYWORDS, keyword, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
    keywordField.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_ONLY);
    doc.add(keywordField);
  }

  private void addLastModifiedToDoc(TestCaseDescription desc, Document doc)
  {
    NumericField modifiedField = new NumericField(LuceneConstants.FIELD_LAST_MODIFIED);
    modifiedField.setLongValue(desc.getLastModified());
    doc.add(modifiedField);
  }

  private void addPathToDoc(TestCaseDescription desc, Document doc)
  {
    Field pathField = new Field(LuceneConstants.FIELD_PATH, desc.getPath(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS);
    pathField.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_ONLY);
    doc.add(pathField);
  }

  private void updateIndex(Document doc, TestCaseDescription desc)
  {
    try
    {
      if (writer.getConfig().getOpenMode() == OpenMode.CREATE)
      {
        // New index, so we just add the document (no old document can be there):
        LOG.debug(String.format("Adding testcase [%s] (%s)", desc.getId(), desc.getPath()));
        writer.addDocument(doc);
      } else
      {
        // Existing index (an old copy of this document may have been indexed) so
        // we use updateDocument instead to replace the old one matching the exact
        // path, if present:
        LOG.debug(String.format("Updating testcase [%s] (%s)", desc.getId(), desc.getPath()));
        writer.updateDocument(new Term(LuceneConstants.FIELD_PATH, desc.getPath()), doc);
      }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Could not create or update index for testcase [%s] (%s)", desc.getId(),
          desc.getPath()), e);
    }
  }

  public void store()
  {
    try
    {
      writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Could not write index [%s]", writer.getDirectory().toString()));
    }
    writer = null;
  }
}
```

## Searcher:

```
import ...

public class Searcher
{
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Searcher.class);

  private final Analyzer analyzer;

  private final QueryParser parser;

  private final File indexDir;

  public Searcher(File indexDir)
  {
    this.indexDir = indexDir;
    analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_34);
    parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_34, LuceneConstants.FIELD_KEYWORDS, analyzer);
    parser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
  }

  public List<String> search(String searchString)
  {
    List<String> testCaseIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
      IndexSearcher searcher = getIndexSearcher(indexDir);

      Query query = parser.parse(searchString);
      LOG.info("Searching for: " + query.toString(parser.getField()));
      AllDocCollector results = new AllDocCollector();
      searcher.search(query, results);

      LOG.info("Found [{}] hit", results.getHits().size());

      for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : results.getHits())
      {
        Document doc = searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
        String id = doc.get(LuceneConstants.FIELD_ID);
        testCaseIds.add(id);
      }

      searcher.close();
      return testCaseIds;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Could not search index [%s]", indexDir.getAbsolutePath()), e);
    }

  }

  private IndexSearcher getIndexSearcher(File indexDir)
  {
    try
    {
      FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.open(indexDir);
      return new IndexSearcher(dir);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
      LOG.error(String.format("Could not open index directory [%s]", indexDir.getAbsolutePath()), e);
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using DOCS_ONLY?! If you only index docids, then you only have a basic inverted index with term->document mappings, but no proximity information. So thats why your phrase queries don't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was that I've indexed and searched with the StandardAnalyzer. Before doing this I've also tried to replace IndexOptions.DOCS_ONLY with IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS but it didn't changed the behaviour. I've posted an answer for people with the same problem.

Comment: I can assure you people do phrase queries with standardanalyzer all the time. But you cannot use DOCS_ONLY if you want positional queries to work.

Comment: So the question is, what I'm doing wrong? I've tried to use StandardAnalyzer and replaced my indexing code for keywords with following code - which will also not work, when querying `private void addKeywordToDoc(Document doc, String keyword)
  {
    Field keywordField = new Field(LuceneConstants.FIELD_KEYWORDS, keyword, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED,
        Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS);
    keywordField.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS);
    doc.add(keywordField);
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you roughly want:

```
keyword:"foo bar"~1^2 OR keyword:"foo" OR keyword:"bar"
```

Which is to say, phrase match "foo bar" and boost it (prefer the full phrase), OR match "foo", OR match "bar".

The full query syntax is here: http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html

EDIT:

It looks like one thing you're missing is that the default operator is OR. So you probably want to do something like this:

```
+keyword:john AND +keyword:"foo bar"
```

The plus sign means "must contain". You put the AND explicitly so that the document must contain both (rather that the default, which translates to "must contain john OR must contain "foo bar").

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was already aware of the lucene query syntax and played around with it. The problem was that I've indexed and searched with the StandardAnalyzer. I've posted an answer for people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by replacing

```
StandardAnalyzer
```

with

```
KeywordAnalyzer
```

for both, the indexer and the searcher.

As I was able to point out that the StandardAnalyzer splits input text into several words I've replaced it with KeywordAnalyzer since the input (which can consist of one or more  words) will remain untouched. It will recognize a term like

```
bla foo
```

as a single keyword.